# Spring Boot / DynamoDB / CrudRepository calling deleteAll throws Unable to make final void java.lang.Throwable.setCause(java.lang.Throwable)

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

Hello I am trying to delete all the items in a DynamoDB Table using the Repository Pattern in Spring Data JPA. I see the underlying implementation for CrudRepository is SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository which delegates the batch delete call too an underlying DynamoDbMapper doing the batch delete in intervals of 100. My question is that SimpleDynamoDBCrudRepository is delegating the call to DynamoDBMapper but the batch delete isn't working. Is this an issue with the

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.derjust</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I believe the issue is with the DynamoDBMapper batchdelete method. It is not working as expected

Comment: List<Matchup> matchups = (List<Matchup>) matchupRepository.findAll();

        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBClient);
        try {
            dynamoDBMapper.batchDelete(matchups);
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
        return matchups;